# How to remove characters from a redirected URL in .htaccess?

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I recently noticed a minor problem in a .htaccess redirect that I can't find a fix for. 
I'm redirecting thousands of links of the form

"example.com/tinc?key={mass of random characters, etc}"

and repointing them at:

"example.com/search.php"

The following .htaccess command works fine:

```
"RedirectMatch 301 ^/tinc.*$ example.com/search.php"
```

...except that I just realised what it *actually* does is send the user to

example.com/search.php?key={mass of random characters, etc}

I *thought* that the .htaccess script directed the user to the new specific URL, but it's actually just replacing the first part of the original URL with the new one.

Because search.php just responds with the valid response that it can't find a match to the string, it's not disastrous, but it's not pretty in the address bar and I'd like it to work properly just for my own satisfaction.

So - can anyone advise how redirect in a way that loses the random string of characters at end, please?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where the problem is, but being more explicit, and defining multiple rules might help:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^example.com/tinc$ example.com/search.php
RedirectMatch 301 ^example.com/tinc\?key=.*$ example.com/search.php
```

If that doesn't work, then assuming that your only GET parameter is `key`, you could try this `RewriteCond`.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^key=.*$
RewriteRule ^example.com/tinc$ example.com/search.php [L,R=301]
```

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Addison, much appreciated, and at least I don't feel like I've missed something obvious now!  Unfortunately, they result in the same problem; the string of characters persists in the form .../search.php?={original string}.   As I say, it's as if the rules are simply resulting in replacement of everything up to the searched text, and leaving everything else in place.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Do you think maybe something is happening to the URL _after_ the replacement occurs? It's not normal that this is happening.

Comment: I don't really know - I tried different strings and had the same result....until just now.   I made up a link that should have failed and found that it now works as intended.  The problem seems to lie in not trapping the "?" symbol.  If I try "http://www.miramodus.com/tinc_add_any_string" it works as intended, if I try "http://www.miramodus.com/tinc?_add_any_string" it includes _add_any_string to the URL.  Not clear why it does this, but trapping the ? mark in .htaccess should fix things.    Many thanks for your help - you've inadvertently solved this for me!